# Is it possible to marshall object in to JSON using any in-built Scala API?

Tags: json, scala

Is it possible to marshall object in to JSON using any in-built Scala API? For some reason, I can't use any library like Jackson, Play etc.

I know Scala provides JSON parser(scala.util.parsing.json.JSON) but I am interested in marshaller.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Marhsalling to JSON... ? I can not understand this because JSON is very specific. Can you give an example.

Comment: Creating JSON text from Scala object graph.

Comment: What is the reason you can't use Jackson or Play library?

Comment: @mavarazy we are doing some prototyping and want to use minimal third party/open source libs

Comment: If you are doing prototyping, Why do you need to optimize used libraries? You need to do it fast, and only then concern yourself with performance and dependencies.

Comment: @mavarazy there is some open source lib usage policy in the organization because of which we are restricted to use certain libs. And this is what prototyping is about. If we find its not possible, then we may relax this policy. Hope this explains our objective.

Answer (score 0):

`case class` and Play's JSON `reads` and `writes` macro can do it for you. [Play's Doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure for what you are looking for. But if you need JSON to respond to some REST API and you are using 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.{RequestMapping, RequestMethod, RestController}

then you can just return a Map like this
Map(
          "startDate" -> startDate.toDate,
          "endDate" -> endDate.toDate,
          "locations" -> myLocations.map { locationId =>
            Map(
              "location" -> locationId.name,
              "locationZone" -> locationId.timeZone
            )
          }
    )

Otherwise play make it easy along with case classes